# How can I load a page by clicking on a menu bar without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu, and I would like to load a page without refreshing it in the browser.

The pages to be loaded are in jsp.

Comment: is it an extern site or intern?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ajax for this.

for example using jQuery:

`onClick="$('#id').load('/path/jspfile.jsp');"`

id is the id of the place you want to plant the page into.

Comment: i have used it but i want o display a accordian which is in robo.html page.

Comment: @Prerna What do you meen by an accordian from robo.html. Where is the original page, what is it called? i'm pretty sure if you want to load an html page you can do the same thing and in the load write robo.html and it will load your html page into the specified div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load content from other page. see example below
you **index.html** and **contact.html**

```
<li><a onClick="$('.content').load('test.html');" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```